# Python set datetime as index and do a forward fill error

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I have multiple dataframes in a list which I iterate through and want to forward fill the date column and set as an index in the below for loop. Unfortunately it is giving me an Atribute Error, any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
## FORWARD FILL TO MINUTE INTERVAL 
for dataframe in dataframes:
  dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)\
            .set_index('date').resample('T').ffill()
```

Outputs the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1770652555927989> in <module>
      1 ## FORWARD FILL TO MINUTE INTERVAL
      2 for dataframe in dataframes:
----> 3   dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)\
      4             .set_index('date').resample('T').ffill()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

And if I tried to assign it to each dataframe using the following code:

```
for dataframe in dataframes:
  dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
  dataframe = dataframe.set_index('date').resample('T').ffill()
```

It does not give me an error, resets the indices and then stops and does not assign the forward fill to each dataframe, hence the output is just a reseted index. Thanks!

Comment: After you call resample, you need to specify some aggregation/singular function, like `dataframe.set_index('date').resample('T').first().ffill()`. This is in case of downsampling.

Comment: In this case I don't think this'd work. It is about upsampling actually!

Comment: In that case, your code should have worked, check whether date column is of type `datetime`